# SQL Query without Temporary Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have written a query which works great on my local SQL Server 2005. I uploaded the query to my hosting server and somehow they say that temporary table creation is disabled on their server.

My query looks like this

```
create table #tmp
(
    srno int identity (1,1) ,
    orderid int,
    orderdate datetime,
    product_code varchar(255),
    product_name varchar(255),
    shipping_cost decimal(18,2)
)

insert into #tmp (orderid, orderdate, product_code, product_name, shipping_cost)
   (select distinct 
      ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, odn.productcode,
      odn.productname, ord.totalshippingcost  
    from OrderNew ord
    inner join order_detailsnew odn on ord.orderid = odn.orderid)

declare @rowcount int, @flag int, @orderid int

set @rowcount = (select @@ROWCOUNT)

set @flag = 0

while (@flag <@rowcount)
begin
   set @orderid = (select orderid from #tmp where srno = @flag + 1)

   if exists (select 1 from #tmp where orderid = @orderid )
   begin
      update #tmp 
      set shipping_cost = 0.0 
      where srno IN (select srno from #tmp 
                     where orderid = @orderid 
                     AND srno NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 srno FROM #tmp where orderid = @orderid))

   end
   set @flag = @flag+1
end

select * from #tmp
drop table #tmp
```

So not sure if this query can be written without a temporary table, joins etc not sure if it will work ? Any advise ?

Comment: What are you trying to do.  Can you explain your db setup and goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume this query is to feed into a report which is why you only want the total shipping cost once, while you don't need a temp table for this for reference you can always do this instead if you need to:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE 
(
    srno int identity (1,1) ,
    orderid int,
    orderdate datetime,
    product_code varchar(255),
    product_name varchar(255),
    shipping_cost decimal(18,2)
)
```

and use @tmp rather than #tmp

But you shouldn't need a temp table for this, see below:

```
SELECT ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, odn.productcode, odn.productname, ord.totalshippingcost
FROM OrderNew AS ord
    INNER JOIN order_detailsnew AS odn ON odn.orderid = ord.orderid
WHERE odn.productcode = (SELECT MIN(productcode) FROM OrderNew AS odn2 WHERE odn2.orderid = ord.orderid)
UNION ALL
SELECT ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, odn.productcode, odn.productname, 0.0 AS totalshippingcost
FROM OrderNew AS ord
    INNER JOIN order_detailsnew AS odn ON odn.orderid = ord.orderid
WHERE odn.productcode > (SELECT MIN(productcode) FROM OrderNew AS odn2 WHERE odn2.orderid = ord.orderid)
ORDER BY ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, odn.productcode
```

Works fine for me with the following test script:

```
DECLARE @ord TABLE
(
    orderid int,
    orderdate datetime,
    totalshippingcost decimal(18,2)
)
DECLARE @odn TABLE
(
    orderid int,
    productcode varchar(255),
    productname varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO @ord VALUES(1, CAST('20110101' AS DATETIME), 50.25)
INSERT INTO @ord VALUES(2, CAST('20110105' AS DATETIME), 78.15)
INSERT INTO @ord VALUES(3, CAST('20110112' AS DATETIME), 65.50)
INSERT INTO @ord VALUES(4, CAST('20110112' AS DATETIME), 128.00)

INSERT INTO @odn VALUES(1, 'aa', 'AAA')
INSERT INTO @odn VALUES(1, 'bb', 'BBB')
INSERT INTO @odn VALUES(1, 'cc', 'CCC')
INSERT INTO @odn VALUES(2, 'aa', 'AAA')
INSERT INTO @odn VALUES(2, 'bb', 'BBB')
INSERT INTO @odn VALUES(3, 'bb', 'BBB')
INSERT INTO @odn VALUES(3, 'cc', 'CCC')
INSERT INTO @odn VALUES(4, 'cc', 'CCC')
```

And my results:

```
Result Set (8 items)  
orderid | orderdate           | productcode | productname | totalshippingcost
1       | 01/01/2011 00:00:00 | aa          | AAA         | 50.25
1       | 01/01/2011 00:00:00 | bb          | BBB         | 0.00
1       | 01/01/2011 00:00:00 | cc          | CCC         | 0.00
2       | 05/01/2011 00:00:00 | aa          | AAA         | 78.15
2       | 05/01/2011 00:00:00 | bb          | BBB         | 0.00
3       | 12/01/2011 00:00:00 | bb          | BBB         | 65.50
3       | 12/01/2011 00:00:00 | cc          | CCC         | 0.00
4       | 12/01/2011 00:00:00 | cc          | CCC         | 128.00
```

edit: I wasn't happy with the above solution, here's a uch faster and more elegant way of doing it:

```
SELECT ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, ord.productcode, ord.productname, CASE WHEN row_no = 1 THEN ord.totalshippingcost ELSE 0.0 END AS totalshippingcost
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ord.orderid ORDER BY ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, odn.productcode) AS row_no, ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, odn.productcode, odn.productname, ord.totalshippingcost
FROM OrderNew AS ord
    INNER JOIN order_detailsnew AS odn ON odn.orderid = ord.orderid
) ord
ORDER BY ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, ord.productcode
```

Results match perfectly.

Edit for user580950, to insert nulls into every second row:

You change the first SELECT line to be:

```
SELECT CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.orderid END AS orderid, ...
```

And you chance the ORDER BY line to be:

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS D(N)
ORDER BY ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, ord.productcode, D.N
```

But as the comments say said in your other question [SQL Query Add an Alternate Blank Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586122/sql-query-add-an-alternate-blank-records/7589494#7589494), this is something that you should be doing at your presentation layer and not in the database.

Comment: One more question Seph, if i have to add Alternate Blank records how do i do that ?

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean? blank lines should really be made at the other end and not within SQL

Comment: ok for example the above query returns 100 records, actually i want it to return 200 records. So first record would be 

1) Actual record
2) Blank record
3) Actual record
and soon...

Now you will ask why i need this its because the result output will be exported to a .CSV and i want each record to be separated with a blank record.

Comment: Someone gave a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586122/sql-query-add-an-alternate-blank-records/7589494#7589494 but its not clear how to ammend that with our join query..

Comment: Thanks for the answer but again one issue it shows blank alternate records but now the problem is one of the column Totalshippingcost is getting displayed the actual value in the BLANK record. I want the alternate row to be BLANK.Here is me updated Query ( edited one ), i think the problem is in CASE WHEN row_no = 1 ?
=============================


SELECT CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.orderid end as orderid,CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.orderdate end as orderdate, 
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.SalesTax1 ELSE 0.0 END AS Tax ,
CASE WHEN row_no = 1 THEN ord.totalshippingcost ELSE 0.0 END AS Totalshippingcost,