# SQL Query Add an Alternate Blank Records

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using following Query to Display Records from SQL SERVER

```
select * from orders
```

Currently this query shows all 100 records in database, what i need is instead of 100 it should show 200 records ( so alternate blank records is fine ) It is possible can it be done ?

Comment: This is best done in the presentation layer.

Comment: Out of interest why would you want to do this? Is this possibly a requirement for the way the data is presented? Presentation logic should really be kept separate of CRUD (create, retrieve, update, delete) operations on the data..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- sample table
declare @Order table
( 
  orderid int,
  qty int
)

-- add some data
insert into @Order
select 1, 10 union all
select 2, 20 union all
select 3, 30

-- cross join the query against two rows       
select case D.N when 1 then O.orderid end as orderid,
       case D.N when 1 then O.qty end as qty
from @Order as O
  cross join (select 1 union all select 2) as D(N)
order by O.orderid, D.N
```

Result:

```
orderid     qty
----------- -----------
1           10
NULL        NULL
2           20
NULL        NULL
3           30
NULL        NULL
```